# Unable to read avi file created by cv2.VideoWriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Everything seems to be written into my avi file output.avi(it is larger than before i started up the program) but i am not able to open it due to error 0xc10100be. How would i go about trying to make the file readable? Also i am fairly experienced with python but openCV is new to me.

Thanks in advance!
code:

```
import psutil
import time
import cv2
import wx
import pyautogui
import numpy as np
import subprocess as sp

running = True
while True:
    if "League of Legends (TM) Client" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
        app = wx.App(False)
        SCREEN_SIZE = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        SCREEN_SIZE = tuple(SCREEN_SIZE)
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
        out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 20.0, SCREEN_SIZE)
        ffmpeg = 'FFMPEG'
        dimension = '{}x{}'.format(SCREEN_SIZE[0], SCREEN_SIZE[1])
        f_format = 'bgr24'
        fps = str(out.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

        command = [ffmpeg,
                    '-y',
                   '-f', 'rawvideo',
                   '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
                   '-s', dimension,
                   '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
                   '-r', fps,
                   '-i', '-',
                    '-an',
                   '-vcodec', 'mpeg4',
                   '-b:v', '5000k',
                   "output.avi"]
        proc = sp.Popen(command, stdin=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
        while True:
            img = pyautogui.screenshot()
            frame = np.array(img)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            out.write(frame)
    time.sleep(5)

cv2.destroyAllWindows
out.release()
```

Comment: how do you close your app? Is out.release() really called? If not, the video file might not be usable

Comment: in addition: Are ffmpeg and VideoWriter recording to the same file?